# Starting a DC motor

Tags: dc-motor

I am driving a DC motor working at 3V with an ATmega8 via a bipolar transistor. The problem is that the motor needs a push to start working. What can I do to solve this problem?

---

This is the circuit that I am using to drive the motor:

[image]

Comment: If it needs a push, then it's either not a DC motor, your power supply is too wimpy, or the motor is partially broken.  We can't tell which from your very vague description.

Comment: Either that, or 3 V (minus BJT forward voltage drop) induces too little current for the motor. If the current is too small the torque might be below the static friction but above the dynamic friction.

Comment: it's a dc one and when it's connected to 3v battery it works correctly

Comment: What is the value of the resistor that connects the microcontroller to the base of the transistor? Is the collector of the transistor connected to the motor or the +3V supply? What transistor (part number) are you using?

Comment: You could try a low threshold volt mosfet.

Comment: i'm using à simple 2n2222a

Comment: A base resistance of 300 ohms at 3V should be enough to drive the 2n2222a to saturation. Why is there a 33 ohm resistor in series with the motor? That 33 ohm resistor would explain why the motor doesn't want to run.

Comment: I have a 5v supply, 33ohm reduces it to 3v.

Comment: Is your ATmega8 running at 5V, or 3.3V?

Comment: Atmega8 is running at 5V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 33 ohm resistor is the problem. You have clearly inserted it to provide a 2 volt drop at 60 mA running current, thinking that this will allow running a 3 volt motor from 5 volts.

It will, as you have discovered, permit the motor to run once it's up to speed. The problem is that a DC motor has a much higher start (or "stall") current than the running current, which is what the motor is spec'ed for. The resistor prevents the motor from drawing enough current to get up to speed.

There is not a simple answer to your problem, which is how to run a 3 volt motor from 5 volts.

Comment: by removing 33ohm, the motor won't support 5v for long time

Comment: @user96729 - Right. That's why I said there is not a simple solution. You can try adding another transistor which pulls down the motor without the 33 ohm resistor, and only turn it on for a second or so. At the end of that time the motor should be up to speed. Now turn off the 2nd transistor, and use the first to maintain the motor speed. But that's not simple.

Comment: You might be better off replacing the 33 ohm resistor with three silicon rectifier diodes in series.  Each diode drops about 0.6V.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your transistor isn't being driven hard enough to supply the start-up current for the motor. Try lowering the base resistor (no lower than about 220 ohms though). Also, make sure you have a catch diode across the motor.

Answer (score -1):

i think the only way to deal with the stall current is by using PWM. the duty cycle will be maximal in starting, then it will be changed to maintain a lower constant current

Comment: Sorry,  i'm still a beginner in Stxg